# Image Processing and Effects in ActionScript-3

Tags: actionscript-3, image-processing, bitmapdata, bitmapeffect

I want to implement various effects like Sepia, GrayScale, Posterization etc. on BitmapData in ActionScript-3.

How to do this and What is most efficient way to do this ?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Sepia, GrayScale you can get away with a [ColorMatrixFilter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/ColorMatrixFilter.html), Posterization probably can be done using the [ConvolutionFilter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/ConvolutionFilter.html). If your target audience has Flash Player 10 installed, I would suggest following @James' advice and look into PixelBender. Should be faster  in most cases(not entirely sure if true for all, e.g. for blur), and it runs on a separate thread/asynchronous processing

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way to do image processing would be to use [Adobe Pixel Bender](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/pixelbender/). This is basically a pixel shader like language that can be used to create filters for Photoshop, After Effects and Flash. There is also an [exchange where developers share filters](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=productHome&exc=26&loc=en_us).

Here is a [tutorial on how to load pixel bender filter into flash](http://theflashblog.com/?p=386).

There is more information available if you [search Google for "pixel bender flash"](http://www.google.com/search?q=pixel%20bender%20flash).

Answer (score 1):

This post explains how to do the GrayScale:

[AS3:How to change a colored Bitmap's BitmapData to black and white?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098890/as3how-to-change-a-colored-bitmaps-bitmapdata-to-black-and-white)

Sepia is a combination of grayscale and tinting.  Tinting is typically accomplished by multiplying one of the colour channels by a certain amount to boost that colour.

The techniques illustrated in that post are the way you should proceed.  You'll have to look up the per-pixel filtering algorithms, but many of them exist on wikipedia or math sites.